# Busted USB port on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: usb, pi-3

One of the 4 USB port on my new pi-3 isn't behaving
Is the port busted, or is there something about the Raspberry 3 USB system that I don't understand. (Or both)?

If I plug a camera in any of the 3 "good" ports I get this from dmesg:

```
usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 71 using dwc_otg<br>
usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=08d7<br>
usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0<br>
gspca_main: gspca_zc3xx-2.14.0 probing 046d:08d7<br>
input: gspca_zc3xx as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/input/input12
```

But if I plug into the bottom center port, I get this:

```
usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 72 using dwc_otg<br>
usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32<br>
usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32<br>
usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 73 using dwc_otg<br>
usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32<br>
usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32<br>
usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 74 using dwc_otg<br>
usb 1-1.3: device not accepting address 74, error -32<br>
usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 75 using dwc_otg<br>
usb 1-1.3: device not accepting address 75, error -32<br>
usb 1-1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device<br>
```

Comment: if you power-cycle the Pi and the camera is already plugged in the suspect port, do you still get this error?

Comment: Yes, same deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the port is damaged, as it is constantly trying to create a new connection to the USB device, and is constantly failing. I recommend that you try plugging in a usb flash drive and see if you can access that, it is unlikely though. What is more likely is that the port is damaged, you may flip the board over and inspect the solder joints by hand which are the most likely points of failure, but the damage may be anywhere between the port and the CPU. Although you pi may still be underwarenty which you can read about [here](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1627216.pdf) (you would fall under the manufacturing defect category)

Comment: Yes, that's what the support folks at SparkFun think too. They are sending me a replacement. These guys are awesome btw. I mentioned that if I sent it back I would be without control for my 3d printer while I wait for the replacement. They said, "no problem, we trust you", just mail it back when you get the replacement (they emailed me a FedEx return label)

Comment: @mjskier glad to hear that you've found a solution to your problem, please mark this answer as correct if it solves your problem.